# jQuery button goes to next element in dom including all children

Tags: jquery

As you can see from the code below, I have a button that I would like go to the next element, and if that element has children, to go to each of those children, recursively going through all levels of the DOM within that container div.

I did find recursive functions for manipulating all of the children recursively, but I want to step into them one by one with the button.

```js
var $currElement = $("#start");
$currElement.css("background", "red");

$("#nextButton1").click(function() {
  if (!$currElement.next().length) {
    // alert("No element found!");
    // return false;    
    $currElement = $currElement.parent();
    $currElement = $currElement.contents().next();
    $("div,p,li").css("background", "");
    $currElement.css("background", "red");
  }
  // if(!$currElement.next().children().length){
  //   $currElement = $currElement.contents().next();
  //   $("div,p,li").css("background", "");
  //   $currElement.css("background", "red");
  // }
  if (!$currElement.contents().length) {
    $currElement = $currElement.next();
    $("div,p,li").css("background", "");
    $currElement.css("background", "red");
  }
  $currElement = $currElement.contents().next();
  $("div,p,li").css("background", "");
  $currElement.css("background", "red");
});
```

```css
div,
p {
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px 8px 64px 8px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

#nextButton1 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery next() example</h1>

<div id="start">This is div 1
  <div>div 1 child</div>
</div>
<p>This is paragrah 1</p>
<div>This is div 2
  <div>div 2 child</div>
</div>
<p>This is paragrah 2</p>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>List 1</li>
    <li>List 2</li>
    <li>List 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>This is div 3
  <div>div 3 child</div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button id="nextButton1">next</button>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's the order that you want the elements to be visited? I think you need to check for children before checking for the next element. After you visit the last child, you go to the next element of the parent.

Comment: And if the parent doesn't have a next element, you go to the next element of its parent, and so on.

Comment: I want to step through them in the order they appear in the DOM.

Comment: Ya I was thinking when I run out of children I have to step back up to the that parent and continue to the next sibling or parent until there are more to iterate through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all the elements in a container. Then you can create a variable that lists all the elements in the container in DOM order, and step through that, rather than navigating the DOM directly.

```js
var $allElements = $("#container").find("div, p, li");
var curIndex = 0;

$("#nextButton1").click(function() {
  $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
  curIndex++;
  if (curIndex < $allElements.length) {
    $allElements.eq(curIndex).addClass("selected");
  }
});
```

```css
div,
p {
  display: block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 2px 8px 64px 8px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px blue solid;
}

#nextButton1 {
  display: block;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

li {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>jQuery next() example</h1>

<span id="container">
  <div id="start" class="selected">This is div 1
    <div>div 1 child</div>
  </div>
  <p>This is paragrah 1</p>
  <div>This is div 2
    <div>div 2 child</div>
  </div>
  <p>This is paragrah 2</p>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>List 1</li>
      <li>List 2</li>
      <li>List 3</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>This is div 3
    <div>div 3 child</div>
  </div>
</span>

<br/><br/><br/>
<br/><br/><br/>
<button id="nextButton1">next</button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why I needed to make the container a span rather than div so it doesn't mess up the formatting of the nested elements. If someone can fix that, feel free to edit.

Comment: That is great! How would I specify which elements to include, e.g. "div, p, li". Or exclude I guess.

Comment: I suggest giving the elements a class, e.g. `class="selectable"`. Then you can use `$("#container .selectable")`

Comment: Good idea but the elements are generated dynamically, so I guess I have a choice of coding that in either method. Is there a way to do that in your solution above?

Comment: I was afraid you were going to add that complication. :)

Comment: you can recalculate `$allElements` each time you click on Next, find the position of the current element in it, then go to the next index.

Comment: lol, I tried this `var $allElements = $("#container *").find("div, p, li");`,   but it just clicks through children only. I'll keep working on it.

Comment: You want `$("#container").find(...)`

Comment: Yes got this to work `var $allElements = $("#container").find("div, p, li");`. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I updated my answer like that, it doesn't include the `ul`.

Comment: Ya my bad, it stops on the div wrapping the ul. I'll find a work around. Thanks Barmar.

Comment: Like I said above, it would be best to give the elements you want to step through a class.

Comment: You could use `div:not(:has(:ul))` so it won't match the `div` surrounding a `ul`.

Comment: Great thanks again :)
If this helps anyone else I added `$(".selected").get(0).scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});` after the last line in the if block for scrollable elements, as in my case. I'm using this for elements that are generated by C# in .NET. I could have coded the classes in that but decided to put it in the jQuery above for personal preference. Cheers~